# GraphQL - sort error - Unknown argument "sort"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, strapi

I need your help in order to sort a GraphQL data by the field createdAt in descending order. When queering by ID, the API, doesn't allow you to sort the array of the given ID.
If i remove the sort key, the query runs ok, but the data is in ascending order (older to new) and I need to retrieve all the new values.

Do you know how can I sort the array?
Thank you in advance!

```
  query GetCategory{
    category(id: 4, sort: "createdAt:desc") {
      data
        {
          id
          attributes
          {
            name
            reviews{
              data
              {
                id
                attributes
                {
                  title
                  body
                  rating
                  createdAt
                  categories{
                    data
                    {
                      id
                      attributes{
                        name
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It depends on the backend schema of the GraphQL API. Does it accept `sort: ...` field? Or is it designed differently? If you can share the schema for the sorting, it could help in answering the query. Do check out this on possible sorting option: [here](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/#:~:text=id%0A%20%20%20%20description%0A%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D-,Sorting,-With%20Prisma%2C%20it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to add the sorting not at top level, but at fields level, because there is only one id (which you can't sort :)), but just because there are nested fields, you have to sort them at child/fields level i.e `reviews (sort: "createdAt:desc")`

The full code is:

```
const CATEGORY= gql`
  query GetCategory{
    category(id: 5) {
      data
        {
          id
          attributes
          {
            name
            reviews (sort: "createdAt:desc") {. <== HERE
              data
              {
                id
                attributes
                {
                  title
                  body
                  rating
                  createdAt
                  categories{
                    data
                    {
                      id
                      attributes{
                        name
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
`
```